# How to let users reference their uploaded files in a CharField?

Tags: python, django

I've created a website in django, which mostly utilises a few simple apps to let a small team of users add events, manage a page displaying uploaded files etc. The most complex part is that each user has a homepage with content that they can manage themselves via a MarkupField (I'm using the one from https://github.com/jamesturk/django-markupfield), plus a series of subpages whose content they also control.

My problem is how to let them upload images and files, and easily reference these on their pages so as to include the images or create a link to the file. The uploading is fine, and the images/files can then be statically referenced if you know where the ImageField is putting them, but the users ideally shouldn't have to know anything about where django actually stores the files or where they are statically served from. My best idea so far is:

1. Create a file/image upload model with the UserPage as a ForeignKey
2. Let the user upload as many images or files as they like for each page
3. Modify the MarkupField to first parse the text and replace some new syntax (e.g. something like '&&IMAGE_1' to reference the first uploaded image associated with the page) with the correct static url for where the referenced imagefield actually stores it.

The downsides of this would be that I'm inventing my own little piece of syntax and have to parse it reliably. That shouldn't be too difficult, but is there an existing way to accomplish the same thing, or an alternative approach worth considering? I'm not sure if I might be missing at least a more natural way to do it within the django framework.

Comment: Just an idea - You can use something like this: https://github.com/Mimino666/django-hash-field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're off to a good start.

A few things it sounds like you might not be aware of:

- FileField, and thus its subclass ImageField, has a [.url](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.url) property.
- If you want to keep your MarkupField vanilla, you can [override the model's save()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods) method to add the extra syntax.

My solution would be to have your template return a list of images with javascript set up so that the user is presented with a list of his images, and can click on one to add it to what she is writing. I like to use [jquery](http://jquery.com) for this sort of thing, but you could also do it in pure javascript. Your list could appear when they click an "add image" button, appear automatically when they start to type image-adding syntax, or both. I would also have thumbnails automatically generated and add a .thumbUrl to the model so that the user could choose the image from thumbnails.

So the idea is along the lines of:

```
function addImgMarkup(imgUrl){
    $('#idOfMarkupTextFormField').val($('#idOfMarkupTextFormField').val()
+ 'imageSyntax' + imgUrl); }
```

in the jquery document.ready function, and

```
{% for uplImg in UserPage.uploaded_image__set.all %}
<a href="#" onclick="addImgMarkup({{uplImg.url}})">
    <img src="{{uplImg.thumbUrl}}" alt="{{uplImg.name}}"></img>
</a>
{% endfor %}
```

in the html.

Please ask if you want clarification on any of this.

Comment: That's very useful, thanks! I'm glad to see my idea seems plausible.

The javascript method would be really ideal, but I didn't originally mention it because I don't know much about javascript - of course I'm willing to learn, and this seems like a good starting point. I guess as long as I implement the basic idea sensibly it shouldn't be too difficult to add a javascript interface later, which would be ideal.